# How to use Gutenberg editor in standalone ReactJS application without/outside wordpress environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to use the latest **Gutenberg Editor** outside from the WordPress ecosystem in my own ReactJS application.

Like the playground used in [the storybook](https://wordpress.github.io/gutenberg/?path=/story/playground-block-editor--default)

Is there any documentation or guide which can help me better understand where to start and how to decouple Gutenberg Editor from Wordpress?

You can think about the example idea:
Gutenberg Bloks Editor works like a charm as a Wordpress page editor and there is no need to reinvent the weel so I would like to get this part of code/module and use it as a HTML Page/WYSYWIG editor in my CMS that I am going to build.

Comment: Hi Sunny, you didn't really ask a question, try and be specific in what you are asking.

Comment: Dear @Duncanmoo, I think Sunny asks a good question. he wanna know an experience about Gutenberg Editor on ReactJS. what is the problem? why you think the question is not really a question?

Comment: @AmerllicA I changed the title from "Using Gutenberg editor outside Wordpress" which is vague and open-ended to "Using Gutenberg editor in ReactJS application", making it more specific, but still it is not a good question as it shows no "this is what I have tried already".

Comment: @Duncanmoo i tried to explain it as better as possible

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, I leave an upvote to neutralize the downvotes.

Comment: That's really a very good question. I'm having trouble with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likey, you should use [react-gutenberg](https://github.com/u12206050/react-gutenberg#readme) library for your ReactJS application.

Comment: I think this  react-gutenberg is used for creating a gatsby / react application on top of the wordpress rest api?

Comment: No, it could be used on a separate ReactJS project. try it.

Comment: It helps me a lot